# Using a canvas to draw a rectangle, why is there always a stroke?

Tags: android

below is my code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
RectF rel=new RectF(100,100,300,300);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rel,30,30,paint);
```

Painted effect：

[image]

After zooming in：

[image]

How should I remove the dark border?

Comment: setAntiAlias(false) still exists

Comment: is your canvas scaled? or translated? post the whole source code of your drawing method, is it `View#onDraw(Canvas)`?

Comment: I use canvas and bitmap to generate a picture and share it to the PC to see the effect.

Comment: i tried. still canot

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved it. After reading your code, I should save the image as png. The image in jpg format will compress the image!  Thanks again!